# How to structure big list of steps in an mobile friendly way?

Tags: lists, mobile-application, multi-step, steps

I need to organize big list of steps in an user friendly way in a mobile app. I was hoping to do it like slider(title + image + description) in onboarding flow but with numbers (ex: 1/20) instead of dots. Or should I go with blog post format?

To provide some context: User can navigate back to list of steps anytime they want.

Any advice on this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

When you set a task with that high of a number of steps to be completed, I think it would be best to present it as a to-do list. Users should be able to see what's in store for them while they continue, maybe make them vertically scrollable like cards?

It would be best to minimize the steps necessary, but I presume you can not, so maybe the user would be able to complete some of the steps, then continue later?

[image]